# Jelly bean offline speech recognition can it be used it in system (PC) with emulator?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, android-4.2-jelly-bean, speech

I just was wondering is it possible to use the android jelly bean's offline speech recognition in the system? like I install the android virtual emulator then install jelly bean download offline speech recognition and then any way I can use it that from my pc. like I do some proxy work any thing and can it be used with notepad/text editor of applications in the desktop? I know desktop app's wont support text input. but I just wanted to know any way I can get that speech recognition out of that emulator to be used in PC ??

Thanks for the answers !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its possible, but I doubt it based on the hardware and software setup requirements for offline speech rec in Android (the answer here hints that it doesn't always work easily on devices [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-rec-in-android-jellybean)).

However, if you are trying to do offline PC voice commands, Windows Speech Rec Macros may  be an option.

See this article: http://lifehacker.com/391884/control-your-pc-with-your-voice