# How to call utter from my application or speech recognization offline

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, offline

I am creating an application which has voice search facility? like in my music player if i want to play some music than i just speak song title than it will play that song. I already try with goggle voice search it works but i want to search off-line.How to do this? So any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to my application [utter!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brandall.nutter&hl=en) I'm working on a [developer API that will appear here in a couple of weeks](https://github.com/brandall76/utter_API_example) time and allow applications to interact with it, providing the user has it installed of course.

Otherwise, for information on using offline recognition, see my [answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674655/1256219)

Answer (score 0):

You have to utilize a speech recognition system with a vocabulary embedded.

If you are using a vocabulary you do not need the web. You can process the information offline.

I think you need something like this:

[Speech recognition by Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=144224)