# Android voice recognition API offline

Tags: android, offline, voice-recognition

Can someone please help me?

I am developing an application with voice recognition via RecognizerIntent.

1. Which Android version brought in officially the offline recognition available to apps by API? Is there any statement about it?
2. By what I read until know it is not a choice of the developer if the voice recognition will be done via online service or the offline dictionaries. Am I right? Or are there any documented API to set offline?

Thanks

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17616994/1256219

Comment: @brandall I wonder whether can I choose the language which I do the recognition? The offline language file support my language (vietnamese) now! I want to create an app which do offline speech recognition FOR my language (vietnamese) ! Is that possible?? Much obliged!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now there is offline voice recognition is possible for android 4.1. check this article
[article](http://www.androidcentral.com/google-search-update-allows-third-party-developers-use-offline-speech-recognition)

and also check [pochetsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/make-your-next-android-app-a-good-listener/ post dates your link and i follow it to settings->input and get no option of voice recognition, but could be it was stripped from custom ROM.

Comment: There is a very good reason why sphinx has not turn around the world... don't waste your time with it

Comment: @pfernandez - What exactly is the reason?

Comment: I don't know why I wrote that, I must have been frustrated or something. I actually use pocketsphinx. It has like... 4 different ways it can be used. But only 1 works without giving false positives all the time (the one in which you have a dictionary with like 4 words, the other document with phrases that combine the words of the dictionary, and the language model with your language phonemes).