# Ionic (Android) speech recognition is not working in offline mode

Tags: android, speech-recognition, ionic2, text-to-speech

I created a very basic app where the app listens to what the user is saying and then prints it out. When I am connected to the internet, it play the "record start" sound to let users know that the recognition has started and then after some time "record end" sound to let them know that the recognition has ended.

When I am offline, the app plays the "record start" sounds and then instantly plays the "record end" sound. In other words, it does not record anything. How can I make the app usable in offline mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android voice recognition API offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684340/android-voice-recognition-api-offline)

Comment: @PavneetSingh As far as I can tell the files are available offline. Why would the starting and end of speech recognition triggered at once because I am offline? :)

Comment: have you checked the log , there suppose to be some indication about why this is happening and do mention your testing environment  details

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the cordova plugin is supporting offline recognition mode. However you can still [**use this library**](http://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/) instead.