# How to control SpeechRecognizer to use offline recognize instead of online recognize?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-voice

I'm new to SpeechRecognizer. I'm wondering is there any way to know SpeechRecognizer is using offline recognize or online recognizer? If so, is there any way to controll SpeechRecognizer to use offline recognize? I read the document and there is no api that can give me the internet usage of SpeechRecognizer. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean

Comment: You can use this link, its working [link]http://swathiep.blogspot.in/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html

Comment: @Jeetendra, your link points to very outdated information. New pocketsphinx for android is here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid