# SpeechRecognizer keeps getting ERROR_NETWORK

Tags: java, android, error-handling, speech-recognition

I'm using SpeechRecognizer to convert voice to text, but I encounter a problem that SpeechRecognizer keeps getting Error_Network (like 80 percent possiblilty). Does anyone encounter this kind of problem.

Comment: mostly it could not able to connect to internet...check your internet permission in manifest...or download language to use it offline

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the internet while using the speech recognizer?
If so , stop all other app (including making phonecalls) using the internet.
If for some reason you cannot do that try working in offline mode, this means that the speech to text will be done locally on the device, thus not needing a network.

Use the following link to set it up:

[Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)