# Speech Recognizer listener ERROR_NETWORK

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, audio-recording

I have a problem with my Speech Recognition listener as topic suggest.
This error appear randomly after I start listening. Problem is just like this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227866/speechrecognizer-keeps-getting-error-network)

Regardles of this answer:

> According to Use of SpeechRecognizer produces ERROR_NETWORK (Value 2), the error was caused by Samsungs speech API (powered by Vlingo). Changing the speech API in the phone settings to standard Google API solved the problems.

I can add that I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4 (and obviously Vlingo recognizer is unchecked)

Ok... my code:

**SpeechRecognizerService.java**

```
@Override
public void cancel() {
    mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
    mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
    listener.setListening(false);
}

@Override
public void listen() {
    mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
    if (!listener.isListening()) {
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        listener.setListening(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void repeat() {
    mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
    listener.setListening(true);
}
```

**SpeechRecognizerIntent**

```
public Intent getSpeechIntent() {
    Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "pl");
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, Config.getContext().getPackageName());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_WEB_SEARCH_ONLY, true);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 100);
    return mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
}
```

**SpeechRecognizerListener**

```
@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(TAG, "on begining");
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(TAG, "on end");
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {    
    Log.i(TAG, error + "");
    service.repeat();
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
}

@Override 
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "on ready for speech");
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    Log.i(TAG, "on results");
    service.manageResults(results);
    service.cancel();
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

}
```

**LogCat when working correctly**

```
01-18 12:56:08.827: I/SPEECH LISTENER(602): on ready for speech
01-18 12:56:09.538: I/SPEECH LISTENER(602): on begining
01-18 12:56:10.969: I/SPEECH LISTENER(602): on end
01-18 12:56:11.670: I/SPEECH LISTENER(602): on results
01-18 12:56:11.740: I/SPEECH LISTENER(602): on end
```

here this is working correctly, but why "on end" trigger twice?

**LogCat when error is triggered**

```
01-18 13:00:42.694: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:42.694: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): 2
01-18 13:00:42.704: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:42.704: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): 2
01-18 13:00:43.185: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:43.415: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:43.415: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): 2
01-18 13:00:43.425: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:43.425: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): 2
01-18 13:00:43.625: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:43.975: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:43.975: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): 2
01-18 13:00:43.985: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:43.985: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): 2
01-18 13:00:44.176: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on ready for speech
01-18 13:00:46.548: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on begining
01-18 13:00:47.979: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on end
01-18 13:00:49.060: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on results
01-18 13:00:49.190: I/SPEECH LISTENER(3202): on end
```

2 means that error is triggered (2 - ERROR_NETWORK)

**Android Manifest.xml - permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I also tried to use my SpeechRecognizer as singleton like someone on stackoverflow suggest, but it changes nothing

I can also add that i cant use offline recognition becouse my language (polish) isn't supported yet.