# android google speech offline

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, speech-to-text

I already downloaded google offline language package, it works in default notebook by keyboard microphone but it does not work in my simple code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE,RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"speak");
mainActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,2222);
```

I had used CMUsphinx before, but I need to speech to recognize a lot of words and sentences, I don't have many sources to make a dictionary.

I want to ask about speech to text is not working offline in google voice?

What kind of language does it support?
Or could anyone give me a suggestion which resource is the most faultless and perfect so I could use, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)