# Android offline voice to text comparison

Tags: java, android, android-library, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I'm trying to build an app to teach some basic english words. It needs to be able to capture audio and convert it to text, which I want to do offline. I know of pocketsphinx-android but my issue is that pocketsphinx tries to relate it with a word from a pre-defined set. This isn't what I want. 
I want the application to just translate the word to text, don't try to figure out what word it is most like, and then check it against a single word. Therefore the program shouldn't try to find the meaning of what the user is trying to say but simply compare it. I also want it to be able to do the opposite (convert text to speech). Is there any available API to do this, or can pocketsphinx do this?

Comment: This question has been asked before, and you can find the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)

Answer (score 0):

Use Grammar file to input all the sentences you need to for example

```
   #JSGF V1.0;grammar menu;
   public <item> =  HI  | LISA  | IS EVERYTHING  | ALRIGHT  | HI LISA  | HI IS EVERYTHING | HI LISA IS EVERYTHING ALRIGHT  ;
```

Your dictionary file should include all the words from the grammar file.