# Android - Speech Recognition Oflline

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline-mode

I am trying to develop an application with some commands & user inputs. Now `Google` provided extra parameter `EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE` for `API 23+` to use speech recognition always in offline mode.

I have check several answers and there is no specification how to use `EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE` constant below `API 23`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean

Answer (score 3):

Yes - [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674655/1256219) about how to configure the device correctly.

[EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE) is only a string constant, which Google 'Now' accepts on any device above 4.1. Just use the string itself instead `android.speech.extra.PREFER_OFFLINE`

Comment: used string `android.speech.extra.PREFER_OFFLINE` and all the steps which allow offline recognition.

Comment: @GauravVachhani Have you tried setting your device Locale to English UK, installed the English UK offline files, reboot your device - then try in aeroplane mode? Sometimes that triggers the offline to work for other languages. If still no luck, what error number is the `RecognitionListener` throwing?