# Offline google voice recognition on android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline

I am working on an android application which will listen to **voice command** and triggers actions accordingly.

**Below are some doubts:**

1. Is google voice recognition offline library is available to use in android apps.
2. Can we create our own dictionary of words & commands with wake up word.
3. Application should work in offline mode(Without Internet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)

Answer (score 7):

> Is Google voice recognition offline library is available to use in android apps.

I think this question is already answered here: [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)

> Can we create our own dictionary of words & commands with wake up word.

This is not possible with Google voice recognition. Therefore I would suggest you a different solution: [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)

> Application should work in offline mode(Without Internet).

Possible with PocketSphinx