# How to integrate Google Voice Recognition Engine on Offline

Tags: android, offline, voice-recognition, offlineapps, google-speech-api

I'm going to use Google Voice Recognition on Android.
I used SpeechRecognizer online, but it needs some time to get the result.
So I'm hoping to use the engine offline and integrate into project.
Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline google voice recognition on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652373/offline-google-voice-recognition-on-android)

Comment: Is there no way to integrate the Google Speech Engine into App project?
And I used also Sphinx, but accuracy is too low.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?)