# Android Voice Recognition without Internet

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice

I am currently trying to create a voice-to-speech application. My phone will be connected to a WiFi that will not be connected to the internet. I am currently using `RecognizerIntent`, and it will take significantly longer because the WiFi has no internet connection.

Is there a way to use `RecognizerIntent` that uses the offline language package immediately instead of trying to connect to Google server first?

I am quite new to this, appreciate the help!

```
private void askSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            "Hi speak something");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

    }
}

// Receiving speech input

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)